# WPF - RibbonControlLibrary not supported with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, ribbon

Today i licensed and downloaded the WPF RibbonControlsLibrary from Microsoft which is an extension to the WPF Toolkit. I've read some tutorials to implement an examlpe [here](http://www.uxpassion.com/2009/08/wpf-ribbon-control-roadmap-and-look-into-the-future/)

When I tried the example is sadly noticed that in XAML i could not access the referenced library.

```
xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"

<ribbon:Ribbon .... >
```

I found out that the Problem lies within Visual Studio 2010 , because in Visual Studio 2008 everything works fine.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue or a workaround to use the library in Visual Studio 2010 ?

Comment: I can't imagine that this is really a VS2010 issue.  Can you describe all of the steps you went through to create your project in VS2010?

Comment: Simple process : Create new VS2010 WPF Project -> unique project name , added Assembly as Reference, in autocomplete feature the reference/assemlby is not listed

Same process does work well in VS2008

Comment: Could it be a Problem with the Framework Version ? I selected Framework 4

Comment: BTW: I found out that i could use the RibbonLibrary with Expression Blend 3

Maybe that is a workaround, but it sucks in my eyes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RibbonControlsLibrary has no problem with VS 2010, I'm telling you because we are using it in our projects; the most common problem is that the library is a **.dll** and when downloaded ,you don't realize because no message or warning is shown but it is automatically blocked by Windows and then inaccessible to VS unless you unblock it which is quick fix; I blogged some time ago about it, you can find the post here: [unblocking the Ribbon Control Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20110203073059/http://www.biztalkand.net/blog/post/Visual-Studio-2010-(Beta-1)-and-Ribbon-Control.aspx)

Comment: Yes I thought that too. So I unblocked it and did a retry but still the designer wasn't able to render. Even after I rereferenced the assembly. Maybe I did something wrong. I guess in most cases this will be the solution for this Problem so i will accept this as solution for this problem. Maybe other searchers will help your answer.

Comment: Thanks.
Not sure about the designer issue (it works for me).
If  you are in your first Ribbon project may I suggest to take a look to http://teusje.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/wpf-office-ribbon-control/
and download the sample  MyRibbonApp (you need to renamed to .zip, also add a reference to System.Xaml) it provide you with the basic Ribbon structure used across most of the projects.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You might be unblocking the wrong dll, probably the one that is output in your bin folder at compile time.

In solution explorer navigate to References folder and click once on the RibbonControlsLibrary. Look in the properties window and note the full path. Copy or navigate to the exact path and from there, right click and go to properties and unblock the dll.

Close your solution, re open it, and build it and it should work.